# evaluate the integral: $\int{(3\csc(x)\cot(x) - 5x^7 +\frac{4}{x} + 3)dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int{(3\csc(x)\cot(x) - 5x^7 +\frac{4}{x} + 3)dx}$$

I know this is a simple problem, but I don't have the answer for it and I just want to make sure that I'm correct!

Comment: Yes, it is a simple problem, at least if you replace $dy$ by $dx$.  And it is even simpler if you don't, because one then gets to assume the $x$ stuff is a constant.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Really, its easier if it is $dy$!  However, it does look like a mistake.

Comment: If you just want to verify your answers, use this: http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp

Comment: Since sometimes equivalent answers can look different, it's often better to verify by differentiating the answer and checking that the result is equivalent to the original function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \int{(3\csc(x)\cot(x) - 5x^7 +\frac{4}{x} + 3)dy} = y(3\csc(x)\cot(x) - 5x^7 +\frac{4}{x} + 3) + \text{const}. $$

So I'm assuming your integral is actually:

$$ \int (3\csc(x)\cot(x) - 5x^7 +\frac{4}{x} + 3) \color{red}{dx}$$

By trig identities $$\csc(x) \cot(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}.$$
Now if we use $u = \sin(x)$ then $du = \cos(x)dx,$ and $\sin^2(x) =u^2.$ So
$$ \int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)} dx = \int \frac{1}{u^2} du .$$

Can you take it from here?

---

*Edit:* the complete integral is then

$$ \int{(3\csc(x)\cot(x) - 5x^7 +\frac{4}{x} + 3)\ \text{d}x} = -\csc(x) - \frac{5}{8}x^8 + 4 \log(|x|) + 3x + \text{const}. $$

Comment: can't you just do $\int{csc(x)cot(x)dx} = -csc(x)$?

Comment: Yes. My answer shows that $$\int \csc(x)\cot(x)dx = \int \frac{1}{u^2} du = -\frac{1}{u} = - \frac{1}{\sin(x)} = -\csc(x)$$ up to addition of a constant.

Comment: oh, well I knew that ∫csc(x)cot(x)dx=−csc(x). I was just looking for the answer of the integral so I could verify it with the one I have on my paper.

Comment: @Kudla69 see my edit.

Comment: okay thanks!  And it actually helped too, I messed up on the log part.

Comment: If verifying your answer is all you wanted to accomplish, perhaps typing your function in wolfram alpha or similar would have been a better option

Comment: well I also wanted to see the work as well :]

Comment: @Kudla69 wolfram alpha shows the work on simple integrals.

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall -1\neq n\in\Bbb R\,\,,\,\int x^n\,dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+K\,\,,\,\int x^{-1}\,dx=\log|x|+K$$

$$\int\csc x\cot x\,dx=\int\frac{\cos x\,dx}{\sin^2 x}=\int\frac{d(\sin x)}{(\sin x)^2}=-\frac{1}{\sin x}+K\,$$